# In emacs "host name must not match ssh"

Tags: linux, ssh, emacs

I'm trying to connect to a server via ssh in Emacs and unable:

```
C-x C-f /ssh:user@1.2.3.4
```

The error in Emacs is  "host name must not match ssh"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/451 i found this so far, might be worth some digging. may be a reoccurance of the bug.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't use a proper Tramp file name. Try

```
C-x C-f /ssh:user@1.2.3.4:
```

See the trailing colon.

Comment: how to disconnect from a ssh session?

Comment: @OskarK.: Tramp is the feature in Emacs that allows remote editing.  Filenames that start with `/ssh:` or any other "tramp method" (defined in `tramp-methods`) use tramp instead of normal file IO.  The ssh session sticks around until you exit Emacs or do `M-x tramp-cleanup-connection`.

Comment: Tramp is bundled with Emacs since version 22.1.

Comment: @OskarK.: Honestly, I don't understand what you want to say to me. When my wife says "Michael" to me, the long variant, I know I've done something not so good. So I'm a little bit nervous now :-)